# how do I make my script produce 12 random divs from 30 - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

At the moment all the words are coming up, but I want the script to produce 12 of the 30 words at random

```
var randomdivs = $("wordstyle").get().sort(function(){
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
}).slice(0,12)
$(randomdivs).show();
```

Here is the list of 30 words that I want the script to pick 12 at random from, I will then display them in a grid for a word game

```
<body>
<div class="wordcontainer">
<div id="randomdiv1" value="mat">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">m</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">a</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">t</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv2" value="man">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle ">m</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">a</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">n</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv3" value="mum">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">m</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">u</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">m</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv4" value="mug">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">m</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">u</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">g</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv5" value="cup">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">c</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">u</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv6" value="sin">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">s</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">i</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">n</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv7" value="sun">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">s</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">u</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">n</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv8" value="pen">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">e</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">n</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv9" value="can">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">c</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">a</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">n</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv10" value="pot">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">o</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">t</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv11" value="cat">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">c</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">a</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">t</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv12" value="gas">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">g</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">a</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">s</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv13" value="nip">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">n</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">i</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv14" value="pin">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">i</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">n</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv15" value="pit">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">i</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">t</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv16" value="tip">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">t</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">i</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv17" value="tin">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">t</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">i</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">n</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv18" value="dad">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">d</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">a</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">d</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv19" value="sad">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">s</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">a</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">d</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv20" value="dim">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">d</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">i</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">m</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv21" value="dip">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">d</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">i</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv22" value="bin">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">b</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">i</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">n</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv23" value="did">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">d</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">i</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">d</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv24" value="mam">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">m</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">a</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">m</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv25" value="map">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">m</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">a</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv26" value="tan">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">t</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">a</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">n</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv27" value="nap">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">n</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">a</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv28" value="sip">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">s</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">i</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv29" value="pip">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">i</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">p</div>
</div>
<div id="randomdiv30" value="sat">
    <div id="1" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">s</div>
    <div id="2" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">a</div>
    <div id="3" class="wordcontainer ui-widget-content wordstyle">t</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var randomdivs = $(".wordstyle").get().sort(function(){  // $("wordstyle") should 
                                                         // be $(".wordstyle")
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
}).slice(0,12);
$(".wordstyle").hide(); // first hide all
$(randomdivs).show()    // then show selected
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/598/)**

OR

```
var randomdivs = $(".wordstyle").hide().get().sort(function(){
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
}).slice(0,12);
$(randomdivs).show();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/599/)**

Comment: Thanks mate I now have it kind of working. Some of the words are not coming together on the other side though. Do you have any ideas to make the letters join up again?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing the "." in front of your wordstyle class selector.
$("wordstyle") should be $(".wordstyle"), right?

With that change it seems to work (assuming styling is correct, e.g. display: none/block).  Here is my jsFiddle to play with it:
http://jsfiddle.net/quant/dhXbG/

Comment: Thanks, but it still displays all 30 words, not 12. Have you any other ideas?

Comment: That was just because the styling was not defined to hide them.  They all showed by default, but the random 12 were logged to the console.  I added some example styling to make it a better demo, but I was trying to stick to the original information you provided and not presume too much.